# Git mv folders up

Tags: git

I need to move folders up with Git without losing history of Java codes.

**Currently:**

```
desktop: ~/projects/github/trunk/myapp
```

The `.git` folder is there in `trunk` not in `myapp` (due to I just imported this repo)

How to I make the `.git` move to my `myapp` folder or do a `git mv` to move all the files and folder from `myapp` to trunk where the `.git` directory is.

Either case is fine. I just need to make sure that the history is retained where when we browse history of file in Git we can see it still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `.git` folder is in `trunk`, there is no need to mv the `.git` folder into `my app`, you can simply use:

```
git rm -rf --cached <file/folder you won't need>
```

to remove the file/folder, which you don't want to be shown in repository, in `trunk` from the index. **(this step is not a must-have)**

then:

```
git add --all app/*
```

to add all the files under `app` to the repository, then:

```
git mv app/* ./
git rm -rf app
```

to move all of the files/folder from `myapp` to `trunk`, and remove the empty `myapp` folder.

then commit the change:

```
git commit -m 'Moving the Java codes'
```

then rename folder `trunk` to `myapp`:

```
mv ~/projects/github/trunk/ ~/projects/github/myapp/
```

Best Regards

Comment: It sounds like the contents of `myapp` is already in Git, so no need to `git add`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth He said when he execute from trunk path, it throws: fatal: source directory is empty, so I thought the files in `myapp` may not in Git and I added this step.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the following is sufficient:

```
git mv myapp/* .
git commit -m "Moved stuff"
```

Comment: It says: fatal: bad source, source=myapp/myapp/*, destination=myapp/*

Comment: When I execute from trunk path, it throws: fatal: source directory is empty,

Comment: @xybrek: Then something weird is going on; is the content of `myapp` a Git submodule?  (Does it also have a .git directory?)

Comment: @xybrek: Did you get any further with this?

Comment: Yeah, the history is there, but in Github for files history started with "Moved stuff" :-(

Comment: @xybrek: Then you must either have had `myapp` as a Git submodule, or the files were never in Git in the first place...